# Resolve to the links probleme

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Net MVC 4, I created a side bar with links through the URL Helper

```
@Url.Action("Core", "Config" )
```

which refers to to the link :

```
 localhost/Core/Config
```

the porblem is when going to another link by the call of URL Helper

```
@Url.Action("Install", "Module")
```

wich refers to the link :

```
localhost/Module/Install
```

in the state bare at hovering to the link it shows

```
/Core/Module/Install
```

which throws an Exception.
Is there any one who have the same problem.

Comment: If any one who have the same problem, I managed to resolve it by calling `@Url.RouteUrl("Default", new { Controller="Core", Action="Config"})` Instead .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any one who have the same problem, I managed to resolve it by calling `@Url.RouteUrl("Default", new { Controller="Core", Action="Config"})` Instead .